# Contour plot with points and line together

Tags: plotting, webmathematica

[image]

I have drawn a contour plot like attached in the figure. Now, what I want is points along with the contour lines. For example: I have a data set like:

```
3.34 4.74 0.0024
3.34 4.76 0.0023
...  ...  ....
```

I need the points (3.34, 4.74), (3.34, 4.76) etc.. on the curve.

My code for this curve is:

```
abc = Import[
  "/home/users/chakrtdm/Desktop/test_25_alpha/ratio-a-b.dat", 
  "Table"]
ListContourPlot[abc, Contours -> 20, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{3.24, 3.38}, {4.70, 4.84}, {0.01, 0.001}}, 
 ContourLabels -> All, 
 TextStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 11, 
   FontWeight -> Bold}, FrameLabel -> {"a", "b"}, Background -> White,
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold]]
```

Please suggest me how can I improve my code to get the points in the contour lines. Thanks!

Comment: You could make a separate plot with the points only and then use `Show`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks:Could you please help me by writing the code? I mean I didn't get that where should I place 'show' command? I am quite new, so apology for not understanding your answer properly.

Comment: If you call `p1=ListContourPlot[...]`  and `p2=ListPlot[the points you want]` then you can just do `Show[p1, p2]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = Table[
  Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}]; ListContourPlot[data,
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{{5, 15}, {10, 5}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by @eldo's `ContourLabels`, a variation that gives color-coded points for labels:

```
ListContourPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], InterpolationOrder -> 3,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 10,
 ContourLabels -> (Tooltip[Graphics[{PointSize[.02], Hue[#3], Point[{#, #2}]}][[1]],
   Column[{Row@{"{x, y} = {", #, " , ", #2, "}"}, Row@{"z = ", #3}}, Alignment -> Center]] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Framed[ContourPlot[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
  Contours -> Join[Range[0, 0.9, 0.1], Range[0.91, 1, 0.01]],
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  ColorFunction -> "Pastel",
  ContourStyle -> 
   Join[Table[Directive[Brown, Thick], {10}], Table[Directive[Dashed, Thin], {9}]],
  ContourLabels -> Function[{x, y, z}, Text[Framed[z], {x, y}, Background -> White]],
  ImageSize -> 600],
 FrameMargins -> 20]
```

[image]